# Android Studio 2.3.2 always asking for gradle update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

I tried updating Gradle Plugin several times but it is not getting updated and instant run is not working. Gradle Console does not show any errors. This message started to show up after updating Android Studio to 2.3.2, before that everything was fine.
compileSdkVersion - 25
buildToolsVersion - 25.0.3

How to rectify this problem? Thanks in advance.

[image: This dialogue pops up every time]

Comment: update the graddle and then restart your computer

Comment: This issue is been there for more than 2 weeks, I have clicked the update button and restarts several times. Even after pressing update the instant run doen't gets activated. So I think the update is not actually completing and does not show any errors.

Comment: Then manually change gradle version in top level (`build.gradle(Project: YourProjectName)`) `build.gradle` file. And sync project.

Comment: Manually changing to 2.3.2 gave me this error "Gradle sync failed: Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Atul\Documents\Projects\Android Projects\NavigationDrawer\app\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your project from edit configurations.

**Follow these Steps**

1). Click on app & then Edit Configurations

[image]

2). Then Click on Update Project & after then Click on apply

[image]

Comment: On clicking update project a message appears to the right of it showing - "Error updating to new Gradle version"

Comment: @AtulVasudevA Have you found any solution? i am getting same error.

Comment: @Maulik patel No solution found. But I changed computer and copied the same project (without the build folder), now everything works good. So it can be a issue with old version sdk or gradle. Also changed grade-wrapper.properties distribution url version to 3.4.1

Comment: @AtulVasudevA My project was developed in Eclipse and now converted in Android studio. is the reason do not work of instant run?

Comment: @Maulik patel I have not used eclipse for my project and still got this error.

Comment: @AtulVasudevA this trick doesnt work for me. i changed districutionurl to gradle-3.4.1.zip

Comment: Just try changing distribution url in gradle-wrapper.properties to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip